# Programs hangs when opening COBOL Indexed file

Tags: cobol, dosbox, cobol85

I've recently started a `COBOL` course and, because of my computer configuration (`Windows 7 64 Bits` and `GNU/Linux 64Bits)` I have to use `Dosbox` to compile and execute programs.

Everything is going well but, I'n finding some troubles when I try to open an `Indexed file`, either `I-O` or `Ouput` mode. I can compile and link but at execution time, `dosbox` get frozen.

My compiler version is `MS-COBOL 5.0` and `DosBox` is 0.74 (last version).

Does anybody have had this issue? Can someone tell how to fix it.

My code is this one.

Thanks in advance.

```
   IDENTIFICATION DIVISION.

   PROGRAM-ID. AGENDA.
   AUTHOR. JOSE MARIA RAMIREZ MIRA.
   DATE-WRITTEN. 06/05/2014.
   DATE-COMPILED. 06/05/2014.

   ENVIRONMENT DIVISION.

   CONFIGURATION SECTION.

   SOURCE-COMPUTER. IBM-PC.
   OBJECT-COMPUTER. IBM-PC.

   SPECIAL-NAMES.
       DECIMAL-POINT IS COMMA.

   INPUT-OUTPUT SECTION.
   FILE-CONTROL.

       SELECT AGENDA ASSIGN TO DISK "AGENDA.DAT"
              ORGANIZATION IS INDEXED
              ACCESS IS RANDOM
              RECORD KEY IS AG-NICK
              FILE STATUS IS AG-STATUS.

   DATA DIVISION.

   FILE SECTION.
   FD AGENDA
      RECORD CONTAINS 112 CHARACTERS
      LABEL RECORD IS STANDARD
      DATA RECORD IS AG-PERSONA.

   01 AG-PERSONA.
      03 AG-NICK                PIC X(25).
      03 AG-NOMBRE              PIC X(25).
      03 AG-APELLIDOS           PIC X(50).
      03 AG-TELEFONO            PIC X(12).

   WORKING-STORAGE SECTION.

   77 AG-STATUS                 PIC 99.
      88 EXITO                  VALUE 00.
      88 CLAVE-DUPLICADA        VALUE 22.
      88 CLAVE-NO-ENCONTRADA    VALUE 23.
      88 SIN-ESPACIO-EN-DISCO   VALUE 34.
      88 FICHERO-NO-EXISTE      VALUE 35.
      88 EOF                    VALUE 10.

   PROCEDURE DIVISION.
   MAIN-PROCEDURE.

       DISPLAY "PROCEDO A ABRIR EL ARCHIVO".
       OPEN I-O AGENDA.
       IF EXITO THEN
          DISPLAY "EL ARCHIVO SE HA ABIERTO"
       ELSE
          EVALUATE TRUE
             WHEN FICHERO-NO-EXISTE
                DISPLAY "EL ARCHIVO NO EXISTE"
          END-EVALUATE
       END-IF.
       CLOSE AGENDA.
       STOP RUN.

   END PROGRAM AGENDA.
```

Comment: You are using extremely old software. Unless the course absolutely demands that COBOL, I'd go for the newer, open-source, GNU COBOL which you can find at Sourceforge. There's support for it. I doubt you'll get any support for MS COBOL V5. See this recent topic, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21970061/indexed-file-processing-in-cobol-error

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Yes, I'm using GNU COBOL (former openCOBOL) plus and IDE build with python, but as you suspect, the course I'm involved asks for programs to be compiled with that version.

Comment: If you have paid for the course, then insist that they assist you with getting this working or give you your money back. It is extremely unlikely that anyone visiting here is actively using that COBOL under DOSBOX for any useful purpose and will be able to assist you. Other than what NealB provided in the other topic, I don't think you'll get much from here. If you are paying for a COBOL course, you don't want to spend days trying to get something simple to work just because the software is 20 years old when there is a spanking new COBOL already on your machine.

Comment: Thanks for your concern. I'm not paying for this course. I thought about using Dosbox in order to get so old stuff working. My teacher says it works well in Windows XP but, as I explain I have Windows 7 and GNU/Linux in my laptop. Anyway, thank you for your response.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried selecting the file using the OPTIONAL phrase.  For example,

```
SELECT OPTIONAL AGENDA ASSIGN TO DISK "AGENDA.DAT"
              ORGANIZATION IS INDEXED
              ACCESS IS RANDOM
              RECORD KEY IS AG-NICK
              FILE STATUS IS AG-STATUS.
```

The OPTIONAL phrase must be specified for files opened for INPUT, I-O, or EXTEND that need not be present when the program runs.

Against this being the problem is your statement that the problem also occurs with OPEN OUTPUT and the program should in any case be producing some output but as others have remarked the version of COBOL is not well known.

By the way I plugged your program into the online COBOL at http://www.compileonline.com/compile_cobol_online.php
and it worked fine triggering the FICHERO-NO-EXISTE condition name.

But this does raise another point.  In my Microfocus manual the file status code of 35 is given as being returned when an OPEN INPUT, I-O or EXTEND is attempted on a NON-OPTIONAL file that does not exist.  A file status of 05 is returned if you have used the OPTIONAL phrase and the file does not exist at the time the OPEN is executed.

Comment: Your course notes are popular, I've seen links to them a couple of times recently. Do you mind if I contact you about one of them through the e-mail link on your website?

Comment: I don't mind people contacting me.  Put COBOL or NIRVANA in the subject to make it through the spam filter.

Answer (score 0):

What is the absolute path to `AGENDA.DAT`?

Sometimes with legacy DOS programs you can't read/write files inside folders with spaces on its name. Say, if your current folder is `C:\ms cobol\` , rename it to `C:\mscobol\`.

It's worth a try, if this is your case.

Comment: Thank you but I was very careful about paths. I think it's an indexed file matter because there's no problem in opening sequetial files.

Answer (score 0):

DOSBox was designed for gaming.
The problem could be DOSBox missing file and record locking.
DOSBox has more issues like internal file caching, a time bomb with multi-user enabled programs.
You could try vDos: http://sourceforge.net/projects/vdos/.
It is Windows only, but integrates better with it.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using GnuCOBOL with VBISAM, then the "filename" must NOT include the file extension on Windows, because it will assume the presence of "filename.dat" AND "filename.idx".

If you are using GnuCOBOL with Berkeley Database to emulate ISAM files, then the ISAM file would not have separate .DAT and .IDX files.  Alternate index files would complicate both situations.

DOSBOX is normally used for running MS-DOS 16-bit software in a virtual machine.  So the older Microfocus COBOL 5 would have to run in DOSBOX on Windows 7.